# Get selected option text from select piker and append it to div on click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have used select picker for creating city dropdown list. 
Now I am doing an exercise in which I have to get that selected option text and append it to the div without the comma(,).

If I have Selected

> City1, City4, City5

Here is my select piker code:

```
<select class="selectpicker citySelectPiker" name="city" id="city" multiple data-style="btn-white" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="1">City1</option>
    <option value="2">City2</option>
    <option value="3">City3</option>
    <option value="4">City4</option>
    <option value="5">City5</option>
</select>
```

Now on click I want that selected text inside div something like this:

```
<div id="job_desc_preview">
   <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light btn-xs">City1</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light btn-xs">City4</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light btn-xs">City5</button>
</div>
```

I have Tried This Script:

```
 var city_string = $('.citySelectPiker').find('.filter-option').text();
```

Basically, I want that comma separated string's each element in different div.

Here is the Div on it clicks I want that comma separated string to placed in div.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect" id="previewButton">Preview</button>
```

Required Output.

> On this button click Want to get the selected(**citySelectPiker**)
>   values and want to place that inside (**job_desc_preview**) div.

Comment: Actually, I have tried that and did not get the value. Just for information, i am selecting multiple values here. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Actually, The Main Problem is that how do I get that each selected value in div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding a value in the div from comma separated string.

First Create String:

```
$('.citySelectPiker').change(function() {
  var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(',');

  console.log(selectedText);
});
```

Now Split that string to an array.

```
var city_array = selectedText.split(',');
```

Now, Add that array value in the div.

```
$('#previewButton').click(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < city_array.length; i++) {       
        '<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light btn-xs">' + city_array[i] + '</button>;';        
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks the help sir, I get the value in the div.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can use `map()` to create an array of the selected options' text content, then `join()` that array together, like this:

```js
$('.citySelectPiker').change(function() {
  var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(',');
  
  console.log(selectedText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker citySelectPiker" name="city" id="city" multiple data-style="btn-white" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="1">City1</option>
    <option value="2">City2</option>
    <option value="3">City3</option>
    <option value="4">City4</option>
    <option value="5">City5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sir i want that string value to placed in the div.

Comment: Then use `$('. job_desc_preview').text(selectedText)`

Comment: Thank for the reply sir, But I want to add that comma separated value in different different div.

Comment: Well then just change the selector. That's just basic jQuery